# Update Single row in on column using Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-ajax

i am using jquery with json data to populate in html table when i do some insert i need just to update multiple row in one column
But not working she give me data like this 'ttesttestetetetetetetete'

(NB) Class lead is my td class in html table

```
function RefreshTable(id) {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/web_service/configuration.asmx/Update",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { id, id},
                    contentType: "application/Json; Charset= Utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#myTable > tbody > tr > td.lead').empty();
                        $('#myTable > tbody > tr > td.lead').each(function () {
                            $.each(data.d, function (index, item) {
                                $('.lead').append(item[0][3]);
                            });
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```

my data is like this

```
{"d":[[21,"Test 1"],[22,"Test 2"],[25,"Test 3"],[26,"Test 4"]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would have been easier if you had posted an example of the data. We do not need to debug your ajax

Perhaps you mean

```js
const data = {
  "d": [
    [21, "Test 1"],
    [22, "Test 2"],
    [25, "Test 3"],
    [26, "Test 4"]
  ]
}


function makeCells(data) {
  const html = data.d.map(item => `<tr><td class="lead">${item[1]}</td></tr>`).join('')
  console.log(html)
  $('#myTable > tbody').html(html);
}
makeCells(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much but she give this error 'Cannot read property 'join' of undefined'

Comment: I would need an example of your data object. Just change any personal data

Comment: There is no item[0][3] in your data. See update